# EMail Filters For DevOps Emails

Tags: azure-devops

I receive emails from a couple of Azure DevOps environments, my company system and a suppliers system. I had rules for the email notifications to move them based on the From address, which was different. Now all the emails come from azuredevops@microsoft.com.

Does anyone know if there is any way to easily distinguish where the email has come from ?

Is it possible to change the From address used by DevOps? I don't believe it is possible to customise the body, and basing the filter on the body is too much maintenance

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a work around in order to filter my emails, in case anyone else has the same issue.

The emails contain links to take you to the work item or other DevOps page that the email is related to. I've been able to create a filter based on the Url that the link is pointing to, so I'm looking for the specific DevOps URL in the Body of the message, as filing the email based on that. It seems to work for my requirements at least.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to change the From address used by DevOps?

The answer is No. The notification from could not be modified by users.

But, I can get what you are suffering. While have the notification emails comes from several organizations, its too messy to know exactly where they come from.

Now, for build or release notification emails, you can create **filter subject rules** to distinguish them. Because in the subject of email which about build or release, it contains the info of organization name.

[image]

But, unfortunately, until now, the org info just displayed in build and release notification. And also you could not customize the email content of notification.

You can raise the demand to [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), follow and vote it.
When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't quite work as the org name isn't always in the subject. I have found a workaround though